# TypeError: Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable in Django

Tags: json, django-views

I am not able to tell what item I touched inmy code. There is this traceback for an error. May somebody help me find the problem and how to solve it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ptar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Ptar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 119, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Ptar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py", line 61, in process_response
    request.session.save()
  File "C:\Users\Ptar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 83, in save
    obj = self.create_model_instance(data)
  File "C:\Users\Ptar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 70, in create_model_instance
    session_data=self.encode(data),
  File "C:\Users\Ptar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py", line 114, in encode
    return signing.dumps(
  File "C:\Users\Ptar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py", line 110, in dumps
    return TimestampSigner(key, salt=salt).sign_object(obj, serializer=serializer, compress=compress)
  File "C:\Users\Ptar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py", line 172, in sign_object
    data = serializer().dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Ptar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py", line 87, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')
  File "C:\Users\Ptar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "C:\Users\Ptar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\Ptar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Ptar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: You can not add a `QuerySet`/model object/... to the session variables.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem. I'd unknowingly copied and pasted a sessions line of code into a wrong place. Thanks for pointing this out, I found it and I'm sorted.